# Using DataSets in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When looping through a DataSet why do you have to user the "(0)"??? Every time I dont use it I get an error, so I have learned use it but not really sure why? Im just trying to get a better understanding of why this is used. Here is an example below:

```
   for each row as datarow in ds.tables(0).rows
   next

   '******Note: If i use this I get an error ********************
    for each row as datarow in ds.tables.rows
    next
```

And also another question comes to mind, with regards to this question is that locally through visual studio 2010 i use that for each statement and it works as expected, but if I use that for each on a production server, if there are no records i get an error, so what I have to do is do a record count, then if ok then go ahead with the for each. Is there anyway around that?

Answer (score 2):

Because your `ds.tables` is an array of tables, and `0` is the first index of the tables array.  It doesn't work in the second scenerio because you aren't defining an index, which is required to access a specific element within your array.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with question one is that the dataset can hold many tables, so you need to either supply an index or table name to access the rows in that table.  I am not sure why there is a difference between locally and production, it should act the same.

Wade

Comment: Thanks I understand completely